# A simpler way to evaluate $\int {dx\over \sin^2x\cos^4x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, alternative-proof

> Evaluate:
>   $$
> \int {dx\over \sin^2x\cos^4x}
> $$

I've started by using identities:
$$
{1\over \sin^2x} = 1+\cot^2x\\
{1\over \cos^2x} = 1+\tan^2x
$$

So the integral becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int (1+\cot^2x)(1+\tan^2x)^2dx \\
&=\int (1+\cot^2x)(1+2\tan^2x + \tan^4x)dx \\
&=\int (1 + 2\tan^2x + \tan^4x+\cot^2x + 2 + 2\tan^2x)dx \\
&=\int (3 + 4\tan^2x+\tan^4x+\cot^2x)dx
\end{align}
$$

I know the integral of $\tan^2x$ and $\cot^2x$, while for $\tan^nx$ one could use a reduction formula. But I find this approach too complicated and seek for a simpler one. Another approach I've tried out is expanding $1$ in the nominator to:
$$
\int {\sin^2x + \cos^2x\over \sin^2x\cos^4x}dx
$$

But that was also clumsy.

Is there another approach simpler than the one suggested above? Could this approach be generalized for integrals of the form:
$$
\int {dx\over \sin^{2k}x\cos^{2p}x}
$$

where $k, p \in\Bbb N$?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a general method when the expression can be written as $$\int P(\cos x,\sin x)\,dx,$$ namely, the tangent half-angle substitution. Substitituing $t=\tan(x/2)$ you get $\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}.$ In your original formula, you get: $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{(1+t^2)^5}{t^2(1-t^2)^4}\,dt$$ which you can then solve by partial fractions.

Comment: Your more general formula is $$\frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\int \frac{(1+t^2)^{2(p+k)-1}}{t^{2k}(1-t^2)^{2p}}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, that is very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{\sin^2{x}\cos^4{x}} dx = \displaystyle\int \sec^2{x}\dfrac{\left(\tan^2{x}+1\right)^2}{\tan^2{x}} dx$.  Now substitute $y = \tan{x}$.

$I=  \displaystyle\int \dfrac{(y^2+1)^2}{y^2} dy = \frac{y^3}{3}+2y-\frac{1}{y} +C$

Comment: The more general equation is $$\int \frac{1}{\sin^{2k} x\cos^{2p}x}\,dx =\int \frac{(1+t^2)^{k+p-1}}{t^{2k}}\,dt$$ where $t=\tan x.$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int {\sin^2x + \cos^2x\over \sin^2x\cos^4x}dx=\int {dx\over \cos^4x}+\int {dx\over \sin^2x\cos^2x}\\
=\int {(\tan^2x+1)\,d\tan x}+4\int {dx\over \sin^22x}\\
=\frac13\tan^3x+\tan x-2\cot2x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$I = \int \frac{dx}{\sin^2(x)\cos^4(x)} = \int \csc^2(x) \sec^4(x) dx$$
and use the trigonometric identities:

1. $\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x) = 1$
2. $\csc^2(x) - \cot^2(x) = 1$

$$I = \int (\cot^2(x) + 1)(\tan^2(x) +1)^2 dx$$
Now use the substitution $u = \tan(x)$; from here the details should be straight-forward.